# functional analysis-inner product space of $C[a,b]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis

Prove that $C[a,b]$ is a inner product space..

Please help me to prove the following axioms or can anybody send me a link which includes these proofs.

1.conjugate symmetry property

2.inner product of $f$,$f=0$ iff $f=0$

Comment: Although this is a very basic and standard inner product space, it'd be a good idea you *provide* the function you want to prove is an inner product (integral and stuff...?). All the necessary stuff usually follows pretty smoothly from the basic properties of Riemann integrals.

Comment: yeah.proving these properties are very basic.but the second property needs some analysis part.so i need to write them correctly.that's why i want anyone to help me.the function is inner product of f,f=integral of f(t)g(t)(bar) form a to b.

Comment: From the "bar" thing I gather you're talking about (analytic?) *complex* functions of a real variable, for which the symbol $\,C[a,b]\,$ is not, I think, usually used: this symbol is used more widely for continuous real functions defined on the closed interval $\,[a,b]\,$ .  Is this correct?

Comment: yes,i'm talking about the complex inner product on C[a,b] with the integral defined above.bar is the conjugate of the function.

Comment: If proving the properties is "very basic" then why are you having to ask somebody else to do it?

Answer (score 2):

$$\langle\,f\,,\,g\,\rangle:=\int_a^b f(t)\overline{g(t)}dt=\int_a^b \overline{\overline{f(t)}g(t)}\,dt=\overline{\int_a^b g(t)\overline{f(t)}}\,dt=\overline{\langle\,g\,,\,f\,\rangle}$$

$$\langle\,f\,,\,f\,\rangle=0\Longleftrightarrow \int_a^b |f(t)|^2\,dt=0\stackrel{\text{by continuity}}\Longleftrightarrow |f(t)|^2=0\,\,\text{on}\,\,[a,b]\Longleftrightarrow f(t)=0$$

Comment: thank you very much DonAntonio..I really appreciate your feed back!!!